# Android - Reference to layout element found but cannot retrieve element

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two layouts one for my main activity and second for my custom dialog which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.51" 
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/a1" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/owner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now in my main activity I have onCreate method:

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(...)
    {
      ...
      if(...)
      {
        // Load the map
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        // Fetch dropdown list & gps button
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.bankslist);
        gps     = (Button)  findViewById(R.id.gpsbttn);

        // When this runs both spinner & gps != null

        // Now I register a listner for my GoogleMap object
        map.setMapMarkerOnClickListener(new ShowDetails(this));

      } else {
        ...
      }

    } else {
      ...
    }
  }
```

Inside my main activity I have an inner class that extends OnMapMarkerClickListener:

```
  class ShowDetails implements OnMarkerClickListener
  {
    private FragmentActivity context;
    public ShowDetails(FragmentActivity context)
    {
      this.context = context;
    }
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker)
    {
      // Check if selected marker is mapped to a Atm
      if(markers.containsKey(marker))
      {
        // Fetch ATM associated with marker
        Atm atm = markers.get(marker);

        // Create a new Dialog instance to display ATM
        // associated data
        Dialog msg = new Dialog(context);

        msg.setContentView(R.layout.info_dialog);
        msg.setTitle(atm.getOwner());

        ImageView logo  = (ImageView) context.findViewById(R.id.logo);
        TextView  owner = (TextView)  context.findViewById(R.id.owner);

        if(logo == null)
        {
          Log.w("ILG", "LOGO IS NULL");
        }

      }
      return true;
    }
  }
```

In this inner class, I'm trying to get a reference to the logo and owner attributes which are part of the info_dialog.xml layout file even tho both are in R. I always gett logo/owner == null. The `findViewById(..)` never returns a valid object.

Answer (score 0):

Since those `View`s are inside `info_dialog.xml` which you didn't inflate with `setContentView()`, you need to inflate that `layout` and use that to get a reference to the `View`s.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = context.getSystemService.(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);       
View root= inflater.inflate(R.layout.info_dialog, null);
msg.setContentView(root);   // can use it here
msg.setTitle(atm.getOwner());

ImageView logo  = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.logo);   // change
TextView  owner = (TextView)  root.findViewById(R.id.owner);  // these lines
```

Comment: In inflate method what is the parent ?

Comment: I used .inflate(R.layout.info_dialog, null); instead however logo is still null.